# Drawing new objects in path of movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

Im making a platform game with bombs, one of which is gonna be a poweder keg. When the player places a powder keg i want to generate a trail of powder from where he places the keg and where he moves. Im just an amateur in actionscript so does anyone have suggestions to how i might do this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are using tile system for your platform game. Then you should only check which tiles are occupied by this powder. For this reason we will use class TrailPowder which stores all Powder sprites with proper handle methods.

**Tile.as**

```
public class Tile {
    public var x:int;
    public var y:int;

    public function Tile(x:int, y:int) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

**Powder.as**

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Powder extends Sprite {
    public var tile:Tile;

    public function Powder(tile:Tile) {
        this.tile = tile;
        this.x = tile.x * TILE_WIDTH;
        this.y = tile.y * TILE_HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

**TrailPowder.as**

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class TrailPowder {
    private var parent:Sprite;
    private var powders:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>();

    public function TrailPowder(parent:Sprite) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public function addPowderAt(tile:Tile):void {
        if (!isOccupied(tile)){
            var powder:Powder = new Powder(tile)
            this.parent.addChild(powder);
            powders.push(powder);
        }
    }

    public function isOccupied(tile:Tile):Boolean {
        var powder:Powder;
        for each(powder in powders)
            if (powder.tile == tile)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    public function clear():void {
        while (powders.length)
            parent.removeChild(powders.splice(0, 1)[0]);
    }
}
```